# Two arithmetical operations in primaryjoin and_ causes failure

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a versioning system of annotations

```
class Annotation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class AnnotationVersion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("book.id"))
    previous_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post_version.id"), default=None)
    pointer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("annotation.id"))
    current = db.Column(db.Boolean, index=True)
    first_line_num = db.Column(db.Integer)
    last_line_num = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Line(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("book.id")
    line = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

I have the following two relationships on the `Annotation` class:

```
lines = db.relationship("Line", secondary="annotation_version",
        primaryjoin="and_(Annotation.id==AnnotationVersion.pointer_id,"
            "AnnotationVersion.current==True)",
        secondaryjoin="and_(Line.l_num>=AnnotationVersion.first_line_num,"
            "Line.l_num<=AnnotationVersion.last_line_num,"
            "Line.book_id==AnnotationVersion.book_id)",
        viewonly=True, uselist=True)
context = db.relationship("Line", secondary="annotation_version",
        primaryjoin="and_(Annotation.id==AnnotationVersion.pointer_id,"
            "AnnotationVersion.current==True)",
        secondaryjoin="and_(Line.l_num>=AnnotationVersion.first_line_num-5,"
            "Line.l_num<=AnnotationVersion.last_line_num+5,"
            "Line.book_id==AnnotationVersion.book_id)",
        viewonly=True, uselist=True)
```

As you can see, the context is simply the `first_line_num-5` and `last_line_num+5`; in other words, the context of the annotation is simply the the prior five and next five lines to the actual body of the text of the annotation.

I am trying to define the same context relationship on the actual `AnnotationVersion`:

```
context = db.relationship("Line",
    primaryjoin="and_(Line.l_num>=AnnotationVersion.first_line_num-5,"
        "Line.l_num<=AnnotationVersion.last_line_num+5,"
        "Line.book_id==AnnotationVersion.book_id)",
        viewonly=True, uselist=True)
```

But this exact definition always returns a failure of

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign
>   key columns for primary join condition 'line.l_num >=
>   annotation_version.first_line_num - :first_line_num_1 AND line.l_num
>   <= annotation_version.last_line_num + :last_line_num_1 AND
>   line.book_id = annotation_version.book_id' on relationship
>   AnnotationVersion.context. Ensure that referencing columns are
>   associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated
>   in the join condition with the foreign() annotation.

If I remove either the `+5` or the `-5` it works. But as soon as I define both, I get that error.

What on earth could cause this particular failure? As you can see it only happens when defined in the `primaryjoin` condition, because it works perfectly as a `secondaryjoin` condition.

Comment: I think you should read https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#creating-custom-foreign-conditions. At least it is explained that determining "foreign" columns is unique to primary join, which explains why your secondary join is working. On a glance your primary does not contain any predicates involving a foreign key that would (directly) connect the involved tables / models. In `Line.book_id==AnnotationVersion.book_id` both are foreign keys to a 3rd table `book`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thank you, I'll go ahead and write the answer, as that solved it. All I have to do is enter `foreign_keys=[first_line_num, last_line_num]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ilja Everila's reference to the documentation helped solve it. All I had to do was specify the `foreign_key` param:

```
context = db.relationship("Line",
    primaryjoin="and_(Line.l_num>=AnnotationVersion.first_line_num-5,"
        "Line.l_num<=AnnotationVersion.last_line_num+5,"
        "Line.book_id==AnnotationVersion.book_id)",
        foreign_keys=[first_line_num, last_line_num],
        viewonly=True, uselist=True)
```